# Retriving all references of a varible inside code

Tags: assembly, operating-system, reverse-engineering

What I am trying to achieve is to find all references of a variable and on what address this happens.

The example does not make sense coding-wise but proves my point.

```
mov ecx,dword ptr [kk (0E9D000h)]  <- Usage one of 0E9D000
mov eax,dword ptr [k2 (0E9D004h)]  <- Usage one of 0E9D004

mov ecx,dword ptr [kk (0E9D000h)]  <- Usage two of 0E9D000
mov eax,dword ptr [k2 (0E9D004h)]  <- Usage two of 0E9D004
```

Address 0E9D000 and address 0E9D004 are inside .data section.

Here we reference the variable kk and k2 2 times. If I have the address of a variable how do I find at which address these variables are used?

My initial idea was to somehow parse the .obj or .pdb file to somehow find all the usages of the symbol and at what address. This is a bit complicated so I have put this idea on hold.
My other idea is to use a dissasembler and loop through the whole .text section and somehow find all references to the variable.

Comment: If you have a complete disassembly then that's just a text search on that, no?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I have the complete source code and ofc disassembly, So you want me to search through the .text section for any usages of that variable address?

Comment: Well, I wasn't considering that you might have all the source, in which case you could look up the variable reference by name, yes? However, if you have the disassembly with the decoded binary code, you can search that for the specific address that you're interested in.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, I will probably have to search for the address like that.  My large scale idea is to relocate the .data section of a program in Windows. For this I will need to edit/path all the instructions that references a variable in the .data section?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but if you have the source code why go through all that trouble?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, How do I get the address of those instructions other wise? This is why I asked the questions. I thought I overcomplicated it but I still did not have another solution.

Comment: Let's go a back a bit: why do you want to relocate the .data section - what's that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, It's to change the address of the variables. I want to relocate the .data section to x place in memory then remove the old one. It's basically a protection mechanism.

Comment: I want to do this during runtime

Comment: There is a whole field of study around this called [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).  If the address of the variable has been captured, it most likely escapes analysis, which is to say when that happens, only in limited scenarios can you continue analysis, and otherwise have to assume that many of a certain class of pointer dereferences access that variable.  Basically, under many common conditions, you can neither statically nor dynamically analyze when that variable is being accessed.  Compiled languages offer no hooks to dynamically detect access.

Comment: So, what you're left with is playing the role of a debugger, e.g. setting data breakpoints.  Or if you're working with bytecode, then having a custom VM that provides data breakpoint hooks.